# Qual è il significato di "false pieghe"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia della bambina perduta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> All’apparenza, dunque, dopo la morte di Rino sembrò migliorare. Smise di stare in allarme a occhi stretti. La pelle del viso, che sembrava una bianchissima vela di olona stirata da un vento forte, si ammorbidì. Ma fu un miglioramento momentaneo. Presto mise rughe disordinate, in fronte, ai lati degli occhi, anche sulle guance dove sembravano **false pieghe**. E un po’ tutto quanto il corpo cominciò a invecchiare, la schiena si incurvò, la pancia le diventò gonfia.

Capisco il significato delle singole parole "falso" e "piega", ma non riesco a cogliere il senso dell'espressione "false pieghe": non l'ho trovato in nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Comment: Forse usato per indicare smagliature della pelle o di cellulite (più improbabile se si parla del viso).

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia:   Un [ricerca su Google di "false pieghe"](https://www.google.es/search?q=%22false+pieghe%22&oq=%22false+pieghe) fa vedere che questa espressione si usa anche in altri contesti.

Comment: Il solo significato che vedo possa applicarsi al contesto tra quelli riportati da Google è quello di pieghe dei vestiti che non siano parte del design (i.e. pantaloni con la piega)

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: quindi, si tratta di  "rughe"?

Comment: Forse intende che sono rughe così vistose (“disordinate”, dice) che sembrano appunto vestiti spiegazzati.

Comment: Sono sicuramente rughe. La frase dice "Presto mise rughe disordinate [...che, le quali] sembravano false pieghe". La domanda è a cosa assomigliassero. Probabilmente @DaG ha ragione a riguardo.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia:  Intendevo quelle dei vestiti: non si usa la parola "ruga" per i vestiti?

Comment: No, mai sentita usare per indicare quelle dei vestiti.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia:  Non lo sapevo. In catalano e in castigliano la parola "arruga" si usa sia per la pelle, sia per i vestiti (e persino per altri oggetti).

Comment: Potrebbe riferirsi alle _pince_, le false pieghe utilizzate nei vestiti. Secondo il [glossario di cucito di Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossario_di_cucito):

    Pince
    pronuncia pèns, piega pinzata, cucita, fatta nei punti di un vestito  
    dove serve per modellarlo sulla forma del corpo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Come possiamo vedere da un [dizionario dell'inizio dell'Ottocento](https://books.google.it/books?id=cqoREH7GrkYC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=false+pieghe&source=bl&ots=W1aOdBJo0v&sig=8UeZ0asYRLfKyrd_4vsd8c25PFc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlw4LbkafWAhWFIsAKHa12DQs4ChDoAQgnMAU#v=onepage&q=false%20pieghe&f=false) e da un [manuale di organizzazione domestica](https://books.google.it/books?id=F9Yj0gFZMqAC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=false+pieghe&source=bl&ots=MbL56PojfO&sig=wdrrn_dpKUTv3YQ4ZUyNoHqVL30&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj58I7hj6fWAhVjOMAKHT3TCtQQ6AEIdDAQ#v=onepage&q=false%20pieghe&f=false), le «false pieghe» sono le pieghe che si formano sui vestiti dove non dovrebbero essere. In questa citazione, Elena Ferrante usa l'espressione in senso figurato: sulle guance, dove la pelle (come il tessuto dei vestiti) dovrebbe essere tesa, tirata, si sono invece formate pieghe.

Answer (score 0):

Provo dunque a dare una risposta a questa domanda.
Da Treccani, definizione di *piega*:

> d. Ruga, grinza nell’epidermide, permanente o prodotta da un
>   movimento, da una particolare espressione, da una smorfia e sim.: con
>   il passare degli anni si formano delle p. ai lati della bocca; con la
>   lunga esposizione al sole le si sono formate tante piccole p. intorno
>   agli occhi; aveva una p. amara sulle labbra

Dunque la grinza, la ruga del viso prodotta da una espressione facciale è una piega della pelle. Nel contesto della frase, quindi, se la piega è una grinza che è prodotta da un movimento o da una espressione, in quanto falsa è proprio una ruga di vecchiaia.

Comment: Grazie, @ealy, ma non capisco perché le rughe di vecchiaia dovrebbero essere "false". È chiaro dal testo che si tratta di rughe del viso, ma si afferma che tali rughe "sembravano false pieghe" ed è quest'espressione quella che non si capisce. Come si ha discusso nei commenti, mi sembra più probabile che faccia riferimento ai vestiti.

Comment: @Charo, falsa piega non piega. A me sembra chiara la spiegazione che ho cercato di dare, ma cerco di essere più preciso. Piega=espressione del viso, come ai bordi della bocca quando sorridi. Falsa piega=ruga di vecchiaia.

Comment: @Charo, come per dire che le rughe che aveva sul viso erano talmente pronunciate che sembravano delle pieghe di espressione, false perché erano date invece dall'invecchiamento della pelle o da quello che stava succedendo...

Comment: La voce del Treccani citata nella risposta usa tra l'altro “pieghe” (senza “false”) proprio nel senso di quelle date dall'invecchiamento (“con il passare degli anni si formano delle p. ai lati della bocca”). Non vedo niente di falso nelle rughe.

Comment: @DaG: la definizione non parla di invecchiamento, ma di tempo, potrebbe essere semplicemente una piega che compare con la ripetizione di una espressione, potrebbe venire fuori anche a vent'anni e in tal caso non parlerei di ruga di invecchiamento. L'aggettivo falso? Immaginiamo che ne so di vedere una persona dopo un po' di tempo e notiamo sul suo viso, quando sorride, delle pieghe dovute all'espressione del momento. Poi smette di sorridere, e quelle pieghe rimangono. Ecco, quelle che prima sembravano pieghe, sono ora false pieghe, cioè rughe dovute all'età. Questa è la mia interpretazione.

Comment: Le "false pieghe" sono quelle che si formano sui vestiti dove non dovrebbero essere. In questa citazione l'espressione è usata in senso figurato: sulle guance, dove la pelle (come il tessuto dei vestiti) dovrebbe essere tirata, si sono formate pieghe.

Comment: @Benedetta: puoi aggiungere riferimenti? Se poi sei sicura usa la risposta

Comment: @ealy: ho trovato un manuale di quella che un tempo si chiamava economia domestica: https://books.google.it/books?id=F9Yj0gFZMqAC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=false+pieghe&source=bl&ots=MbL56PojfO&sig=wdrrn_dpKUTv3YQ4ZUyNoHqVL30&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj58I7hj6fWAhVjOMAKHT3TCtQQ6AEIdDAQ#v=onepage&q=false%20pieghe&f=false

Comment: @Benedetta: comunque non mi dispiaccia la tua interpretazione, mi piacerebbe una risorsa un po' più autorevole:-) Ma tu comunque, se sei convinta, prova a rispondere...

Comment: @ealy: un vocabolario dell'Ottocento è più autorevole? https://books.google.it/books?id=cqoREH7GrkYC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=false+pieghe&source=bl&ots=W1aOdBJo0v&sig=8UeZ0asYRLfKyrd_4vsd8c25PFc&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlw4LbkafWAhWFIsAKHa12DQs4ChDoAQgnMAU#v=onepage&q=false%20pieghe&f=false

Comment: @Benedetta ti incito a rispondere:-) Mi piace la tua risposta

Comment: @Benedetta: anche a me piacerebbe avere questa tua risposta.

Comment: @ealy: va bene, ma non so quale fonte usare… :-) va bene il vocabolario? o è troppo antico?

Comment: @Benedetta: secondo me puoi usare tutte e due le fonti che hai trovato.

Comment: @Benedetta: fai come suggerisce Charo

Comment: @Charo: grazie! Scrivo la risposta con le due fonti.

Comment: Poi, @Charo, per favore, potresti sistemarmi l'indicazione dei link delle fonti? Grazie.

Comment: Grazie, @Charo!